# yii2 creating passcode before accessing webpage

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I needed a modal pop up to ask for a passcode. I did the following but it always redirect me to login page. And it seems like the session wasn't created at all.

main.php (layout)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>PASSCODE</h4>
            </div>
            <form role="form" id="myform" action="site/passcode">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <!--<label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Enter Passcode</label>-->
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passcode" placeholder="Enter Passcode">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="passcodeBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick="btn_click()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
        //$_SESSION["user"] = "permit";
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#passcodeModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            })
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#passcodeModal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>";
    }
?>
<script>

    function validatePasscode_click()
    {
      var pc = document.getElementById('passcode').value
      //document.getElementById("passcodeform").submit();
      //
      console.log("inside click");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/site/passcode',
        data: {name: pc, _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()},
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            console.log("ajax");
          var resp = response;
          var answer = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
          console.log(answer);
          if(answer == '123'){
            $('#passcodeModal').modal('hide');
        }
    }});
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

I validated

CONTROLLER

```
public function actionPasscode() {
    // a list of available cities
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)  {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $passcode = $data['name'];
        $_SESSION["user"] = "permit";
        if($passcode == '123'){
            if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
            { 
                session_start(); 
            } 
            $_SESSION["user"] = "permit";
        }
        return json_encode($passcode);
    }
}
```

I need to validate the passcode using ajax then set the session so for every other page, they won't ask for the passcode again if you have entered before

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not created because in Yii2 you create session differently from what you're showing in your code. Yii2 uses [yii\web\User](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) class for authentication and session storing.

Basically, you should be using something like:

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 3600 * 24 * 30);
```

Where `$this->getUser()` returns:

```
static::findOne(['email' => $email]);
```

This is taken and was a little bit modified from **Basic template** and that's exactly how Yii2 stores user session. Your own created session might (and probably is) conflict with Yii2's session management.

Please try using this method.